# Adding two non-relation Entities to DbContext that second entity use the first one's Id entity

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

in code first, When I want to save 2 related entities (for example Country entity and City entity), first, I create an instance of Country and second create an instance of City and put object of Country to navigation of City, at last SaveChanges.in this process Database, first, create the Country and then put its Id to CountryId field of City entity and save city to database. so now, I want to do the same but with non-related entities. this means I want to send 2 entity (without relationship) to DB, that fist, first one saved and second one get its Id, and use it, at last Save...

Comment: First, you need to post some code if you expect to get a reasonable answer.  Secondly, if they **aren't related**, why do you need the Id of the first object before saving the second?

Comment: In my project, I used Repository and UnitOfWork. I have to do Log for every CRUD (saving the records to another Database (having History of records)). I do this in Repository methods. in Update and Delete, I have no problem, because I have the Id but in Insert I have no Id in Repository.

Comment: and also, I don't  want do Log in all controllers' methods, because it's not Centralized and I have to write a lot of codes...

Comment: Well, having 2 databases means you have 2 contexts, which is not how your question is worded.  Also, the Id value of an entity is populated automatically by EF when saveChanges succeeds, so you definitely should have it to pass to the other db....